# Resharper's Intellisense not show method summary

Tags: resharper, intellisense

The pic below is the Visual Studio's Intellisense.
[image]
The pic below is the Resharper's Intellisense, but it doesn't show the method summary(description).
[image]
I've reinstalled Resharper(latest version) but it doesn't work.
Here are my Visual Studio's and Resharper's config.
This problem troubled me a long period. Anyone could give some help to me, thanks.

Resharper update to version 2017.1.3, issue still existed.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Raphael, I tested it on my side with the same configuration that you shared, the parameter information works fine in Resharper, please check this screenshot: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKgm7N7dq_Ifx0eM6w. Since this issue is relates to the Resharper and it is better to redirect to this appropriate forum: https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics to seek for a more professional support.

Comment: Hi Sara. Thanks for your help. I've post a issue to the jetbrains support website.

Comment: JetBrains Support confirms this issue is a bug if your Resharper's version is before 2017.2. Update Resharper to latest version could solve this problem.

Comment: Hi Raphael, so glad to hear that your issue is solved and thank you for your sharing, please add a reply with your solution and mark it, that can help other community members to easier search this useful information, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JetBrains Support confirms this issue is a intellisense bug if your Resharper's version is before 2017.2

Solution: Update your Resharper to the version equal to or later than 2017.2 could make your intellisense work properly.